# Calculate price based on post code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, form-submit

I am designing a wordpress page on which i can add my own php code on as well.

I want to be able to add a form that users can enter their post code and based on their post code I wish to display a price.

So far I have come up with this, but need help in adding the IF statement to it:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Post Code: <input type="text" name="post_code" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
Your Post Code is: <?php echo $_POST["post_code"]; ?>!<br />
And the price for that post is:
```

Can someone help me here please?

Appreciate your help in advance! :)

Comment: not exactly sure what you want help with? Designing the whole thing? What is the `if()` for? Finding the price based on postal code? Do you have the list in an array? database? etc;

Comment: I need help with writing to IF statement to calculate the price based on the post code.
The post code is a selection of 10 in a format of 'SL1 2SA' 'SL1 2GP' 'SL2 3FA' and so on
Thanks

Comment: there are only 10 possible post codes? really?

Comment: No I will only be using the possible 10, if anything other than those 10 then I will display a message to say 'Sorry but your out of our range'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewritten based on commetns

```
<?php
//$_POST["post_code"]='SL1 2SA';
$post_price=array('SL1 2SA'=>'1.50', 'SL1 2GP'=>'2.99', 'SL2 3FA'=>'3.47');

$postage=$post_price[$_POST["post_code"]];

if(!empty($postage)){
    echo 'Your Post Code is: '.$_POST["post_code"].'<br>And the price for that post is '. $postage; //1.5
}else{
    echo 'bad post code';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$code = $_POST["post_code"];
    if($code == '043132'){
$price = '15';
elseif($code == '632432'){
$price = '20';
}
```

If you need some elaborate structure, you need an mysql database, and you can organize this script in other way..

Comment: So how could I integrate that with the code above? I do apologise here for my stupidity :$